# Create a PostgreSQL table from a SAS table

Tags: postgresql, sas, sqldatatypes

I am creating a  PostgreSQL table from a sas table and the sas table is showing below.type of column woe is numeric and other column are type of char.

```
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+
| variable | new_variable | type | start | end | woe |
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+
| A        | mi_A         | char | 1     |     | 1.3 |
| A        | mi_A         | char | 0     |     | 0.6 |
| B        | mi_B         | char | 1     |     | 5.4 |
| B        | mi_B         | char | 0     |     | 0.1 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 3     |     | 1.3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | @0    |     | 0.6 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 2     |     | 5.4 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | N     |     | 0.1 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 1     |     | 1.3 |
| gnd_cd   | gnd_cd       | char | 99    |     | 0.6 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | 0     |     | 5.4 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | Y     |     | 0.1 |
| mar_sign | mar_sign     | char | N     |     |   6 |
+----------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+
```

the client shows an error:syntax error at or near "end".I think the error may possibly caused by the "start" column.still don't why and how to fix it.
my code is simply a sql,and tableA is for postgresql and tableB is from SAS:

```
create table schema.tableA from select * from mywork.tableB;
```

any advice are appreciated！

Comment: Is the above your code?

Comment: What are your data types on the columns in the two systems?  Also, make sure you double-quote the field names as `end` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL to signify the end of a transaction.

Comment: @vol7ron SAS table for column "start" is char (for more information,SAS only have numeric and char type)there is no data type yet in postgresql,I create it directly from SAS table.

Comment: SAS is much more flexible in allowing keywords for variable names. In your postgresql code you might need to add double quotes around variable or dataset names to prevent it from thinking you are typing a keyword.  So use `select "end" from ...` .If you do then watch out for case of the names.

Comment: Post the SQL code that is causing the error and the actual error message.

Comment: @J.Cooker. Do you want to create the postgresql table using pg sql code or sas code?

Comment: SAS numericals will translate to postgress doubles

Comment: @Tom it's the reason.thank you for reminding me of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS is much more flexible in allowing keywords for variable names. In your postgresql code you might need to add double quotes around variable or dataset names to prevent it from thinking you are typing a keyword. So use

```
select "end" from ...
```

If you do then watch out for case of the names.  Without quotes Postgres will default to creating/searching for name in all lowercase.  But once you add the quotes then the value in the quotes must match exactly the variable name. So if you create variable named `Name` it will actually create a variable named `name` and you can reference as `NAME` or `NaMe`.

But if you create a variable in mixed case using quote, like `"Name"`, then the uppercase `N` will be in the variable name and you must use `"Name"` to reference it. `Name` without the quotes will not work since it will look for variable with lowercase, `name`.